# Floating Action button trapped inside toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I created a floating action bar, and for some reason it is trapped in my toolbar, I can't move it from the top of the screen. I want to have it in the bottom corner but it does not let me move it.

Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".Chat.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabTextColor="#ffffff" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is where I created my floating buttom:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.hackriddle.textwithoutbarriers.Main2screenActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Well, you have android:layout_alignParentTop="true" set

Comment: I tried removing that, and it did not work.

Comment: From the FAB View?

Comment: Please provide an image

Comment: Better , if you change the root layout from relative layout to coordinator Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `layout_gravity` and `layout_alightParentTop` use `layout_alignParentBottom`, `layout_alignParentRight` and `layout_alignParentEnd`

Like this:

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
>     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
>     app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
> ```